# How can I access the SVG image from static resource

Tags: visualforce, css

I am trying to access a .svg image from the static resource but I am unable to access it using the below code.I have tried to access other images they are accessible.

```
<apex:page controller="CheckStaticResources" >
<style>
    div{          
    background-image : url({!URLFOR($Resource.SetupForImages,'images/alert-white.svg')});
    background-size: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>    
    <apex:form >
    <div class="infos"> demos   </div>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct format to display SVG. You need to frormat it like

```
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account" title="description of icon when needed">
  <svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon">
    <use xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account')}"></use>
  </svg>
  <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account Icon</span>
</span>
```

Also note that:

> To use the SVG spritemap icons, add the attributes
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" to the  element as
>   documented in the Trailhead module. Do not add the attributes to
>   individual  elements as can cause a page rendering bug.

Take help from here: [Use Images, Icons, and Avatars](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_design_system/units/lightning-design-system5)

As you want to do use it into css so you need to do something like

```
<a href="/" class="logo">
  Kiwi Corp
</a>

.logo {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 82px;
  background: url(kiwi.svg);
  background-size: 100px 82px;
}
```

Reference : https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: I want to access the image in the CSS Class.

Comment: @user49538 check my updated answer.

Comment: When I used     background: url({!URLFOR($Resource.SetupForImages,'images/back-black.svg')}); in the css class the image is still not accessible

Comment: have you checked the path is correct and you are not getting 404m in console @user49538